# Passing/binding an Object call as a parameter to a UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have the main Window called `"DataEntryForm"` and 2 `UserControls` `"Identification"` and `"SamplingInformation"` which are embedded in the main Window as tabs.

I have an object called Report that is called in `"Identification"` UserControl

I need to bind/call/pass the Report Object to `"SamplingInformation"` UserControl

```
<Window x:Class="Frontend_WPF.Forms.DataEntryForm"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Frontend_WPF.Forms.User_Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Data Entry"  Width="800" Height="600" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow"  >
<Viewbox Stretch="Fill" Margin="0">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="695*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
        <TabControl  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="TabControl" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Grid.RowSpan="1" >
            <TabItem Name="ID">
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock Name="IDHeader" Text="ID" 
                 ToolTip="IDENTIFICATION"/>
                </TabItem.Header>
                <Grid>
                    <local:Identification x:Name="Identification_UC" />
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Name="SamplingInformation">
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock Name="SIHeader" Text="SAMPLING INFORMATION" 
                 ToolTip="SAMPLING INFORMATION"/>
                </TabItem.Header>
                <Grid>
                    <local:SamplingInformation x:Name="SamplingInformation_UC" />
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox >
```

My Objects

```
public class Report{

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")] 
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "code")] 
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "date")] 
    public DateTime date{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "SamplingInfo")] 
    public SamplingInfo samplingInfo { get; set; }
 }

public class SamplingInfo 
{

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")] 
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Name")] 
    public string name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "type")] 
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

Can I pass the object and use it in the "SamplingInformation" UserControl, or is there a way to bind it directly to it?

Comment: You can bind the DataContext of `local:Identification` to the `local:SamplingInformatio` so that both Tabs represents the same object.

Comment: "I have an object called Report that is called in "Identification" UserControl". there is no indication of that on the provided code sample.

Comment: Use a shared `DataContext` for both `UserControls`? What's the point of defining some properties only in the `DataContext` of `Identification` if you want to be able to bind to the same properties in `Identification` or vice versa? That sounds like a design flaw.